# JFrame hide a part in design tab

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, windowbuilder

I'm newbie to Swing. I installed Window Builder in Eclipse to draw an interface but I got this problem. `JFrame` hides a part in design tab.

[Here is image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wfGIy.png).

How can I fix this?

Comment: Works fine for me. But tell me, do you want to learn _Swing_ or do you just want to use _WindowBuilder_ to build a GUI?

Comment: I want to use WindowBuilder to build a GUI first

Comment: Do you mean that you want to start learning _Swing_ after you finish building a GUI with _WindowBuilder_?

Comment: Yes, I start learning Swing after finish building a GUI

Comment: I suggest that you do it the other way around. Start learning _Swing_ first. I recommend starting here: [Creating a GUI With JFC/Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html)

Comment: Ok, thank you very much! But my teacher want me to building a GUI first

Comment: Did you ask your teacher for help with your problem?

Comment: I asked him this morning and he hasn't replied me. Maybe I will ask him tomorrow